# Keeping an element bottom of td

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have `td` which has a background set to bottom. 
And I want to keep my `h2` tag on top of that background. But the height of `td` may change from one `td` to another.

What I expect is something like below. Is it posible to do with `css` Any help?

[image]
Thanks

Comment: is anything supposed to go between the h2 and the background? if not, then make a div with the background picture and the h2 where they need to be.  you can control the size of the div

Comment: css td valign="bottom" & add padding to the td on the bottom?

Comment: Do you want the h2 to be positioned *vertically* above the background, or on a *z-index* above the background? Your choice of words is ambiguous, although your image suggests you mean the former.

Comment: @mblase75 I need z-index above the background

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding your background to the h2 element (using CSS) instead of to the td. Then use `vertical-align: bottom` on the td to force it to the bottom.

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/Bxxx5/

```
td {
    vertical-align: bottom;
    text-align: center;
}
h2 {
    background-image: url(whatever.png);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `vertical-align: bottom` on your table cell and add some `padding-bottom` that matches the height of your background.

http://jsfiddle.net/SCqPp/

Edit : If you want it to sit *on top* of the background, just remove the bottom padding, like this : http://jsfiddle.net/wqAkF/

Comment: I tried that,but when the height of td changes, h2 moves away

Comment: are you using display:inline-block or using floats?

Comment: seems like misunderstanding, I mean i wanted to keep the h2 with same level of background. I have updated the question. sorry for that

Comment: Added a second version without the bottom padding.

Answer (score 0):

Just put a padding bottom on the `td` the height of the background image.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the code, hard to say.  But you could probably use

`vertical-align:top;`

for the `td`

Comment: in his case, `vertical-align: bottom;`